# --tf_initial_checkpoint for ADE20k Data Set

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using DeepLab Tensforflow API to do some semantic segmentation training.

The github repository:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab

After running successfully the training on pascal data set, I have tried to test the ADE20k data set. so I download the data set and I used this command to run the training.

```
python deeplab/train.py \
     --logtostderr \
    --training_number_of_steps=1000 \
    --train_split="train" \
    --model_variant="xception_65" \
    --atrous_rates=6 \
    --atrous_rates=12 \
    --atrous_rates=18 \
    --output_stride=16 \
    --decoder_output_stride=4 \
    --train_crop_size=513 \
    --train_crop_size=513 \
    --train_batch_size=4 \
    --dataset="ade20k" \
    --fine_tune_batch_norm=True \
    --tf_initial_checkpoint="{???????????}"
    --train_logdir="deeplab/datasets/ADE20K/exp/train_on_trainval_set/train"\
    --dataset_dir="deeplab/datasets/ADE20K/tfrecord"
    --min_resize_value=513 \
    --max_resize_value=513 \
    --resize_factor=16 \
```

Please how can I specify the checkpoint directory.

Answer (score 0):

The train_logdir represents the checkpoint directory. The train_logdir is an input to the checkpoint_dir argument of the tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession utility. The checkpoints are saved/restored to/from this directory.

Comment: thank you. I have just a problem with initial checkpoint, and where can I find it. I think all the checkpoint are her https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md

Comment: For xception_65, you can use the following model: xception65_ade20k_train. The initial checkpoint will be the path to this directory. For ex:
`--tf_initial_checkpoint='/path/to/dir/deeplabv3_xception_ade20k_train/model.ckpt'`

Comment: Thank you, I will test this